# Delete the only one page in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Whenever I want to refresh my `UIPageViewController` I call the following snippet, including when I want to delete a `viewController` from my `UIPageViewController`.

```
[self setViewControllers:@[currentViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Everything is working just fine... except when I want to delete the one and only `viewController` from my `UIPageViewController` because I cannot pass an empty array as the first parameter. In fact I get an exception if I do so.
How can I force a refresh and not set the current `viewController` for my `UIPageViewController`?

Right now I am passing a dummy `ViewController` but I don't find that very pretty. If I do so I get a page indicator even though I am returning zero in my `(NSInteger) presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController*)pageViewController` overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question makes no sense. There is no such thing as a page view controller without a view controller. If your goal is to hide the page view controller's view, hide it (or even rip the whole thing right out of the interface).